# How to add Custom plugins into KeystoneJS Admin UI ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, keystonejs

Is there a way to add custom plugins to KeystoneJs Admin UI without messing around with the source code too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

many people want this kind of functionality — there are a bunch of open [issues on github](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues):

- `#2088` – 0.4: How do I create new Field Types for KeystoneJS v0.4?
- `#1898` – Plugin Architecture
- `#1386` – FieldType "plugins"
- `#1137` – Cannot find ways to add a custom button or links in Admin UI

this is not possible in `0.3` without modifying the keystone source code, although [keystone-custom-fieldtypes](https://github.com/kadosh1000/keystone-custom-fieldtypes) seems to work around this.

I believe it is planned for `0.4`, which is not ready yet.